# How can i change the decimal precision and cancel the rounding of float numbers

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I'm using odoo 8 and i imported an excel file which i introduced float values with 3 digits after the decimal point. After importing the data in odoo 8 as a tree view i noticed that odoo only displays 2 digits after the comma  for these digits and it does the rounding however i want to keep the values as is in the excel file (without rounding and with 3 digits after the decimal point). Any idea for help please ?[image]

Comment: You need to change the decimal precision for your field.

Comment: Settings--> technical--> BD structure --> decimal precision  then i need to add my  field ?

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Okk , Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the decimal precision using `digits`.

> > digits=(6, 2) specifies the precision of a float number: 6 is the total number of digits, while 2 is the number of digits after the comma. Note that it results in the number digits before the comma is a maximum 4